# ¿Cómo funciona inherit?

Tags: html5, css

Tengo este código, no entiendo como funciona `inherit`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    span {
        color: blue;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .extra span {
        color: inherit ;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div>
    Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
    </div>
    
    <div class="extra" style="color:green">
    Here is <span>a span element</span> which is green, because it inherits from its parent.
    </div>
    
    <div style="color:red">
    Here is <span>a span element</span> which is blue, as span elements are set to be.
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `span` hereda el color de su parent `.extra`

Comment: @ReneLimon cierto, ahora entiendo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este indica que la propiedad heredará ese valor de su elemento padre. Puede ser utilizada en cualquier propiedad CSS y en cualquier elemento HTML.

```
span {
    color: blue;
}

.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Ejemplo: Establece `text-color` para los elementos `<span>` a `blue`, excepto aquellos que estén dentro de elementos con `class="extra"`.

Según: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp